# Prevent user from entering numbers but keep the alphabetical characters they have already entered

Tags: regex, reactjs

I'm trying to stop user from entering numbers in an input form but keep alphabetical characters. At the moment,as soon as the user enters a number, my code erases everything entered before, e.g. "Ann3" turns to an "". 
I don't know how to keep "Ann" when the user accidentally hits "3". This is what I've got so far:

```
    updateName(event) {
    var value = event.target.value;
    var model = this.state;
    if (!value.match("^[a-zA-Z]*$")) {
        value = "";
    };
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: value })
```

I wonder if I could use concatenation here, I'm sorry, I'm new to ReactJS and programming in general and don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did a code sample with react [bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) but i'm sure it will work for you:

```
  let { FormGroup,ControlLabel,FormControl } = ReactBootstrap;

  class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

      this.state = {
        value: ''
      };
    }

    getValidationState() {
      const length = this.state.value.length;

      if (length > 3) return 'success';
      else if (length > 2) return 'warning';
      else if (length > 0) return 'error';
      return null;
    }

    handleChange(e) {
      this.setState({value : e.target.value.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '')})
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <form>
          <FormGroup
            controlId="formBasicText"
            validationState={this.getValidationState()}
          >
            <ControlLabel>keep alphabetical characters</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              type="text"
              value={this.state.value}
              placeholder="Enter text"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <FormControl.Feedback />
          </FormGroup>
        </form>
      );
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Example />, 
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
```

https://codepen.io/ene_salinas/pen/zmMyOb?editors=0010

Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than setting `value` to the empty string, you could use `.replace` to replace all non-alphabetical characters with the empty string (thereby keeping alphabetical characters and their relative positions):

```
updateName(event) {
  const { value, name } = event.target;
  this.setState({ [name]: value.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '') });
}
```